How to listen to received transaction coin with ethers + web3modal
I want to listen user send coin to my wallet, so I used ethers + [walletconnect][1] to write code, using NextJS. here is my code:
const { walletProvider } = useWeb3ModalProvider()
async function listenToTransaction() {
    if (!isConnected) throw Error('User disconnected')

    //https://docs.ethers.org/v5/single-page/#/v5/api/contract/example/-%23-example-erc-20-contract--connecting-to-a-contract--erc20contract
    const ethersProvider = new BrowserProvider(walletProvider)
    // const ethersProvider = new WebSocketProvider('wss://bsc-mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/39de56957e2e43e48f31d9415d0c2eb7');
    const singer = ethersProvider.getSigner()
    const contract = new Contract(address, abi, ethersProvider)
    // Listen to transfer event
    contract.on('Transfer', (from, to, amount, event) => {
      console.log(from, to, amount, event)
      if (to.toLowerCase() === address.toLowerCase()) {
        console.log(`Received ${formatUnits(amount, 18)} tokens from ${from}`);
      }
    });
  }

I run this code but got error:
@TODO Error: could not coalesce error (error={ "code": 4200, "message": "ethers-unsupported: EthereumProvider does not support calling eth_newFilter" }, payload={ "id": 3, "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "eth_newFilter", "params": [ { "address": [ "0xc80fdbaabcd2ab61234b19722da53d692c6f9152" ], "topics": [ "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef" ] } ] }, code=UNKNOWN_ERROR, version=6.13.2)
Could someone please help me. I search many topic but still dont know what i need to do
Here is my Context to controler the wallet account:
const mainnet = {
    // chainId: 1,
    // name: 'Ethereum',
    // currency: 'ETH',
    // explorerUrl: 'https://etherscan.io',
    // rpcUrl: 'https://cloudflare-eth.com',

    chainId: 56,
    name: 'Binance',
    currency: 'BNB',
    explorerUrl: 'https://bscscan.com',
    rpcUrl: 'https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org'

    //testnet
    // chainId: 97,
    // name: 'Smart Chain - Testnet',
    // // currency: 'BNB',
    // network: 'bsc testnet',
    // nativeCurrency: { decimals: 18, name: 'Smart Chain - Testnet', symbol: 'BNB' },
    // rpcUrls: { default: 'https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/' },
    // blockExplorers: { default: { name: 'BSC', url: 'https://testnet.bscscan.com' } },
    // testnet: true
}
// 3. Create a metadata object
const metadata = {
    name: 'BNB Minging Game',
    description: 'BNB Minging Game',
    url: '.........', // origin must match your domain & subdomain
    icons: ['https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/12321']
}
// 4. Create Ethers config
const ethersConfig = defaultConfig({
    /*Required*/
    metadata,
    auth: {
        email: true, // default to true
        socials: ['google', 'x', 'github', 'discord', 'apple', 'facebook', 'farcaster'],
        showWallets: false, // default to true
        walletFeatures: true // default to true
    },
    /*Optional*/
    rpcUrl: '...', // used for the Coinbase SDK
    defaultChainId: 1 // used for the Coinbase SDK
})

// 5. Create a AppKit instance
createWeb3Modal({
    ethersConfig,
    chains: [mainnet],
    projectId,
    featuredWalletIds: [
        //https://explorer.walletconnect.com/?type=wallet
        '4622a2b2d6af1c9844944291e5e7351a6aa24cd7b23099efac1b2fd875da31a0'
    ],
    enableAnalytics: true // Optional - defaults to your Cloud configuration,
})


Filters are not supported by all software-as-a-service nodes. You likely need to run your own node to get a filter. Instead you can try WebSocket subscribe APIs (if available) or poll block ranges for events using eth_getLogs to see if there are new deposits.

Regardless of the eth_newFilter error, which I will explain how to fix  later, you have a bigger problem to solve.
Simple transfers between accounts do not produce logs, so you cannot listen for EVM events for those cases.
You are trying to use an example that involves a smart contract, but my understanding from the question and from the code you posted is that you want to listen for transactions to your EOA (External Owned Account) 0xC80FdBaabCD2aB61234B19722Da53d692c6f9152.
In the case of smart contracts, if the code includes events, the contract can write logs in the transaction receipt, and you can create a filter to wait for a notification when that specific event is fired.
On the other hand, to listen for a simple transfer to an address, you need to list all the transactions in a block, and then locally filter the transactions based on the recipient address.
To listen on a new block to get the list of transactions to check the recipient in it, you can use a filter, but the filter operation must be supported by the JSON-RPC provider you are using.
You can use your own provider (suggested, so you can enable all the features you want and you can verify the result is true), or you can use an external provider.
I see you want to use Infura.
Infura supports eth_newFilter for BSC (BNB Smart Chain), see documentation here, so you get this error because ethers.js gets an HTTP 401 error, but it cannot interpret the real message, which is:
Project ID does not have access to this network, see https://infura.io/dashboard
See this example calling the JSON-RPC provider directly via curl:
curl -v https://bsc-mainnet.infura.io/v3/39de56957e2e43e48f31d9415d0c2eb7 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jsonrpc" :"2.0", "method": "eth_newFilter", "params": [{"topics": ["0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef"]}], "id":1}'

> POST /v3/39de56957e2e43e48f31d9415d0c2eb7 HTTP/1.1
> Host: bsc-mainnet.infura.io
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 149
>

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2024 21:59:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 81
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Origin
< Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="Auth failure, project ID does not have access to this network"
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

project ID does not have access to this network, see https://infura.io/dashboard


So it seems that you have created an API key, but you haven't enabled BSC in the Infura Endopint settings page (see screenshot below).

Once you have configured the API correctly, the filter creation should work, but again, it will not return the events you are looking for in any case.
So now you have two options.

Listen to each new block created with the eth_newBlockFilter operation, or
manually list each block you are interested in. You periodically call an eth_blockNumber operation to get the latest block, and for each block you haven't processed yet, you call an eth_getBlockByNumber operation.

For each block you get, no matter how, you list all the tx and filter them for to.toLowerCase() === "0xC80FdBaabCD2aB61234B19722Da53d692c6f9152".toLowerCase().
I suggest method 2 because it is more reliable, you can run it from time to time, and you don't risk losing transactions if you are offline for some reason.
With method 1, if you disconnect and reconnect, you lose all the blocks in between. Also, any network problem will cause you to lose blocks containing potentially interesting transactions.
Side note. Refresh your API key you posted in the code, otherwise anyone can use it and consume your request quota, and in general never post API keys or credentials publicly, even if they are test API keys.
